# STM32F401 failed the search for probes ensure that the usb drivers are installed

Tags: stm32, st-link, iar

I have a stm32f401vc discovery card, I can't download and debug the code
you can find the error in this picture

[image]

when I connected the card to my pc here is what I found in Device manager

[image]

I worked on this card for a long time and this is the first time that I find this error

Comment: BT seems to have a problem, but that is probably unrelated. The COM port is there, there should also be an STLINK entry under Universal Serial Bus Devices (whatever that is in French). I presume you've shut down the computer completely to power-off (not hibernate or sleep) and restarted it, then plugged in the USB? Try a different USB port after reboot.

Comment: it doesn't work too

Comment: the serial com is worked too but i can't download and debug

Comment: Do you have another board to try?

Comment: no i don't have another board

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I got the exact same error message when trying to program my device and I could not find much information about this error message. I'm posting this answer here in case anyone runs into the same issue.

In my case the reason was that I had connected a Segger J-Link programmer while my IDE (IAR Embedded Workbench) was configured to use a ST-Link programmer. Updating the configuration to use the J-Link solved the problem for me.

Based on this, I would guess that this message is coming from the ST-Link driver, which is searching for an ST-Link programmer and cannot find it.
In case of the original poster, the STLink is connected however, as can be seen in the Device Manager. Maybe the driver is outdated and must be updated? Or maybe it was just a glitch and reconnecting the USB cable would help?